# segue does not work in simple segue test

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue

I have a weird problem. I have created 2 viewcontrollers in my storyboard: *testSegueViewcontroller* and *nextPageViewController*. 
The testSegueViewcontroller contains a UIButton NextPage. I Ctrl-dragged from this button to nextPageViewController and created a Push segue.

The problem is when i run this program and clicking on the NextButton in the testSegueViewcontroller it does not show the nextPageVieController :-(

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 31):

With this approach you should use modal segues. Push segue is a part of *UINavigationController* transitions

If you want to use push segue then you will need to put your *testSegueViewcontroller* into *UINavigationController* instance. This will allow the Push segue to work.

Comment: thanx for the answer, i did not realize the fact of the uinavigation controller.

Comment: You are welcome! Please take into account that it is better to follow the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to get all the best from this site %)

Comment: Don't know why this isn't marked as the answer already.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks! this save me from turning insane!! I've been debugging and googling for hours!

Comment: how can i put it in UINavigationController ?

Answer (score 1):

Push segue is a part of navigationcontroller if your viewcontroller is embed with uinavigation controller then only you will able to push the controller to another view. If you don't want to add navigation controller then use modal transitions.

Comment: thanx for the answer, i did not realize the fact of the uinavigation controller.

Comment: which problems you are facing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `testSegueViewcontroller` inside a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: thanx for the answer, i did not realize the fact of the uinavigation controller.