# segue called but not fired

Tags: xcode, storyboard, segue

i use storyboard for the first time and i have a problem with segue, my storyboard is like this:

```
                                           __ ViewController
                                          /
                       __ TabBarController
                      /                   \__ ViewController
                     /
 -> TableViewController
                     \
                      \__ NavigationController ___ ViewController
```

I create 2 segue, one for TabBarController and one for NavigationController with identifiers "AddServer" (for NavigationController) and "GoMainBoard" (for TabBarController). From my TableViewController with a custom test, i fire TabBarController or NavigationController with this code

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [_tbvDownloads deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; 

        if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AddServer" sender:self];
        } else {
            ...
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoMainBoard" sender:self];
            ...
        }
    }

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddServer"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        ...
    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GoMainBoard"])
    {
        UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

- (void)prepareForSegue is called but my TabBarController is not fired, can anyone explain me where I made a mistake ?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the push segue only works inside a navigation controller. In other cases you would have to use 'modal' type instead. Hope that answers your question :)

See also: [segue does not work in simple segue test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768658/segue-does-not-work-in-simple-segue-test)