# Segue is using the wrong animation

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, segue

I'm using a push segue to go from a View Controller into an Animation Controller. I have a push segue in my storyboard file, and this is the code I'm using in my `prepareForSegue` method:

```
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Push To Table Segue"]){
     NSLog(@"Push to table segue called");

    ReccyTableViewController *loginViewController = (ReccyTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This is the code that calls the next segue:

```
- (void)goToNextView {
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Push To Table Segue" sender:self]
}
```

The segue works, but the new window flies up from the bottom, rather than being pushed. How can I make it pushed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in prepare for segue, you should only "prepare", and not performing the animation.

Moreover, you are not using your segue animation here, but the animation from `presentViewController`, which I think is a modal animation by default. You have literally nothing to do to perform your segue, except calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` if you want to do it programmatically, or clicking the button/cell/whatever you linked in your storyboard.

EDIT : According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8768805/1343969), you can use a push Segue only inside a `navigationController`. If it is not the case, you could either insert them and hide the navigationbar, or create a custom Segue.

Comment: I have called `performSegueWithIdentifier`, but if I don't put the `presentViewController` in my `prepareForSegue` method, then nothing happens.

Comment: How have you configured your Segue ?

Comment: I'm calling the segue from a timer, so I can only link the `segue` from the `view controller` to the next `navigation controller`

Comment: What is the style of your Segue (in your storyboard) ? I've done segue  from ViewController to ViewController, and I did nothing more than calling `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Are your controllers in a `navigationController` ?

Comment: I see. I've settled to use a modal segue and use a fade in transition. Thankyou!